# What is the use of declaring a pointer to a structure with typedef?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

As in the image I've declared a pointer to a struct, one with typedef keyword and another without typedef keyword, and I'm trying to assign the address of the same user-defined array, but I'm getting an error at line number 19.

When I comment out line number 19 and build the project, no error occurs at line number 20.

[image]

Comment: By the way. No one can see the image. I recommend copying and pasting the code into the question as text and then indenting the whole thing in 4 spaces (select the code use the {} button or CTRL+K keys to indent the whole block). That always works.

Comment: OK we can see the image now, but you, and everyone else, are far, far better off with text than with an image.

Comment: I may have misinterpretted the question. Are you asking what `typedef` does or are you asking why one would use `typedef` for this case?

Comment: You're mixing your metaphors. `NODE` is a _typedef_ (i.e. a type). `NODE2` is a global scope _pointer_ to a `struct node`. You can assign a value to `NODE2` because it's a variable. The convention is to _not_ use all caps for a variable because the all caps is used for constants, such as `#define PI 3.14159`. Better to do `struct node *my_node_pointer;` or `NODE my_node_pointer;` But, you _can't_ assign a value to a _type_. Thus, `NODE = arr;` is invalid.

Comment: I am voting to close this since all of the code is in an image. Also you're missing the *error message* and this is not the entire code excerpt.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct node *NODE;
```

Introduces a synonym `NODE` for the **type** `struct node *`. You cannot assign a value to a type, therefore the line

```
NODE = arr;
```

fails compilation.

```
struct node *NODE2;
```

Introduces a global variable named `NODE2` of type `struct node *`. You can assign to this variable as you wish, therefore the line

```
NODE2 = arr;
```

does not give an error.

---

The above is similar to the following:

```
typedef int Int32;
int Counter;

...

Int32 = 5; // error
Counter = 5; // valid
```

Comment: @SagarTube: `NODE` is an alias to `struct node*` <-- the pointer is important. Otherwise yes.

Comment: So,According to the answer   

`NODE` is just an alias to `struct node`

whereas `NODE2` is a global variable of `struct node*`

fine but 

now consider a code where malloc is used to create a memory block and malloc returns a void pointer and so inorder to use the memory block we have to typecast to a particular type
of pointer and using `NODE` keyword we can do it instead of `struct node*` 
eg:
`NODE x = (NODE) malloc (sizeof(struct node));`

how is this possible?

Comment: @SagarTube: what's the problem? `NODE x = (NODE)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` is the same as `struct node *x = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` Also note that you don't need to write an explicit cast in C, only in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign values to a data type.

typedef essentially creates an alias for your user-defined data type from struct.

When you use

```cpp
typedef struct node *NODE;
```

it creates a name `NODE` whose *data type* (`struct node *` here) is given by typedef.

On the other hand, if you were to not typedef it, and simply write it as

```cpp
struct node *NODE;
```

it would create a *pointer variable* of type struct node. (and not a data type)

Comment: typedef creates an alias for a data type that already exists. `struct` creates a user-define data type

Comment: @M.M Thank you, corrected!